# Three law judicial system

Tags: government, law

### Premise

Most of the time, the simplest answer is the best one. For instance, a complicated and convoluted judicial system is kind of hard to keep track of: "does this law interfere with this law?" "Is this violation tolerable under this law?" "Is this person eligible for this under our policy if this law restricting that law allowing this law is in effect?" and so on.

I would like to propose, as a case study in government, a judicial system with three simple laws. But first, let's define "entity," what the law is protecting:

**An entity is a single individual *or* multiple individuals who are affiliated, and the assets that belong to them.** "Affiliated" just means they identify themselves as a group. For instance, a human and their house, a company, and a homeowner's association are all entities, but Vito Corleone and the Xenomorph Grid are not.

Alright, now on to the laws:

1. **Nothing may be done to an entity without said entity's consent.** For instance, you can't injure a person (unless he/she consents) because that would be harming the cells of the person. You can't steal, either, because you are taking part of an entity without someone else's consent. (Remember, we defined entity as an individual(s) *and* their belongings.)
2. **An entity who violates any of the laws must be punished with a consequence equal to that of the violation, decided by the populace.** For instance, if Albert Fish were brought before a jury today, and they said, "yeah, we're just going to let you walk free," they would be punished for not punishing another person.
3. **No action that may lead to a violation of the 1st and 2nd law may occur.** For instance, a company can't omit information about their product; while not directly harmful, it may cause an accident. Similarly, one cannot aid, abet, or give refuge to a criminal, because that would mean a violation of both the 1st and 2nd law.

---

### Question

After that lengthy premise, it's finally time to move on to our question: **Would such a system work, and if so, what scenarios might arise? And if not, what *would* happen instead?** I'm interested in hearing what anyone might say. You can make up other elements of this scenario, such as capital punishment for any violation, add another law, etc.

Note: If anyone wants to fix a small loophole or add another law, feel free to do so *if and only if* you deem it necessary for this system to function.

---EDIT---
Let's assume humanity has implanted computers in their brains to help with processing scenarios, because ZeissIkon brought up the excellent point that such a system is inevitably headed towards analysis paralysis.

Quick clarification: these laws function like Asimov's 3 laws. They're meant to be imperfect. I just want to see how imperfect they are.

Comment: I foresee a society mired in analysis paralysis.  No one will be able to do anything for fear of violating or allowing a violation of the law.

Comment: It sounds like you invented Libertarianism :)

Comment: @ZeissIkon I thought so too, because you'd physically have to sort through every possible scenario.

Comment: "What scenario might arise" is too broad. We could fill entire books discussing that ;) Please try to reduce the scope of the question.

Comment: @KeizerHarm Big difference is libetarian society doesn't make it impossible to be a capitalist -- a sensible judge will throw out frivolous cases, but "the populace" will itself become paralyzed trying to decide what's sensible and what's silly, because they'll never agree.

Comment: Interpretation is the big issue here. The laws are so vague that it is impossible to unequivocally apply them. For instance, having punishments and sentences imposed by the populace will result is public opinion, and not precedent, determining how individuals are treated by the law. What is consent mean? Legally consent is one form of legal contract of which there are many. The body of law is so large because of the difficulty in trying to fairly consider and cover all possibilities and loopholes, not complexity for the sake of complexity

Comment: I can see you were inspired by Asimov's three laws. I don't think yours would balance out like Asimov's. To much room for opinion of "what is damage" and human fickleness/ruthlessness.

Comment: What's the point of the third law? It basically boils down to "Obey laws 1 and 2". If it comes down to the "may lead to" part, you've made otherwise legal actions illegal. Building a house, for example, is illegal, because it "may" one day collapse and hurt someone.

Comment: Given how hard is is for people on earth to agree about whether the legal systems, hundreds of thousands of people have devoted their lives to studying, work or not. Why do you expect this legal system to have a more definitive and less opinion based answer?

Comment: I don't consent to being forced to obey laws. I don't consent to you breathing in earshot of me or for you to require me to get consent to kill you, therefore I just kill you. I also don't consent to be arrested or pay taxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are dystopian laws. *Very* dystopian laws. Let's break down the rules, one by one.

First Law: **Nothing may be done to an entity without an entity's consent**. Okay. But a lot of things need to be done to you without your consent. For instance, I'm answering your question and I'm not asking for your permission. And not only that, I'm giving you an answer that you might not like. And, in fact, *I don't care whether or not you give me permission*. If you post a comment to this answer and say 'I don't like this answer, please don't attatch it to my question', I will ignore you. It's nothing personal, it's because this is a Q&A site focused on getting the right answer, so we approve of the free exchange of ideas.

The concept of 'nothing may be done to an entity without an entity's consent' will apply mentally as well as physically, which means that we've stoppered the flow of ideas, such that the only ideas you hear are the ones you *want* to hear. Needless to say, this is bad.

There are even problems when it deals with physical things too. For instance, let's say you go into a coffeehouse and order a cup of coffee. The owner then decides that he doesn't like you and wants to kick you out of the store. Physically. With his foot. Who's right? Would he be harming you because he's kicking you, or perhaps since you're in his entity (i.e. the coffestore he owns), and you're in contact with it against his permission, you're actually harming him when he kicks you out.

That's not to say that it's a bad concept - it's a good one! But without restrictions and explanations it's too easy to abuse. Next law.

Second Law: **An entity who violates any of the laws must be punished with a consequence equal to that of the violation, decided by the populace.** A punishment 'equal to the violation' isn't that easy to determine. Let's say I cut off someone's arm. Should *I* get my arm cut off in exchange? But how would that help the person who's arm I cut off? And, if I have to re-compensate him *and* get my arm cut off, how is that fair to me to get punished twice? Let's say I just have to pay him - how much do I pay him? Do I pay him more if he's, say, a professional one-handed juggler who can function without his arm or if he's a world-class chef that can no longer cook?

Clearly, a punishment fitting the crime isn't something that's simple and evident. And then the system you propose to determine it is mob rule. This is never a good idea - democracy, after all, is two wolves and a lamb voting on who to eat for dinner. It's incredibly exploitative of minorities, read: *any* type of minority; be it skin color, social status, skill set, or anything in between. Not to mention that you'll need a system to determine how to decide punishments, and that's a system ripe for corruption itself.

Third Law: **No action that may lead to a violation of the 1st and 2nd law may occur.** In other words, it's illegal to violate the laws, and you must do your best to uphold them. Which is something that a dystopian government would happily tell it's citizens - follow the laws and punish anyone who violates them.

All in all, these aren't evil concepts, but the nature of power is to corrupt. The reason why we have a myriad of laws is to stop people from abusing them. Not to mention that, yes, even with the best of intentions, it can lead to terrible results. The First Law shuts down all interactions, the Second Law will give the mob the fangs it needs to punish whoever it hates at the moment, and the Third Law tells all the citizens that resistance is futile.

Given that the punishment system is derived from mob rule, it's my assumption that this civilization will eventually decline as the punishment for every infractions keeps ramping up and every person seeks to find ways that everyone else has oppressed them to exercise those punishments.

Answer (score 4):

Words do not have absolute meaning; English is not mathematics. You have three laws, and they seem to mirror the Libertarian ideal of the [NAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-aggression_principle): commit no harm, fraud or coercion. Hardcore Libertarians would love to see a government whose only job it is to enforce the NAP, and leave the free market to sort out everything else.

However, in practise, a law only means what the interpreter says it does. It is the duty of a lawyer to interpret the law in the way best suited to his client, and it is the judge's duty to try to interpret it as objectively as possible, but there is always room for interpretation; otherwise trials would be only as long as the time it takes to discover all the evidence.

Lawbooks are lengthy in order to leave as little room for interpretation as possible. You cannot just use a noun like *consent*, or a verb like *leading to*, without writing an entire subsection exactly detailing the extent of those words within the context of what you are describing.

You describe only "entity" coherently, but every other word in your laws is subject to a wide span of possible meanings. It is not just possible to interpret them differently; it is the *duty* of advocates to do that for their clients. Let's just take the first law:

> Nothing may be done to an entity without said entity's consent.

- What is "nothing"? Does that include harmless things? Will I be sued for giving my wife a surprise gift?
- What is "done to"? Am I allowed to water my yard if it means that droplets might land on my neighbour's porch? Will I be tried, and will I be punished by an equal amount of water on my head? What if I'm a musician and I need to practise every day, can my neighbour sue me and subject me to hours of ear-splitting noise?
- Nothing may be done to an entity... by whom? If a meteor lands on my house, can we sue that meteor?
- Assuming the implied subject is "by another entity" - and people's belongings are part of an entity: can I be sued for my dog peeing on my neighbour's yard? How about if I have a beehive, and my neighbour keeps flowers; can he sue me because my bees are stealing his pollen?
- What is "consent"? This is not just rape laws, which are already complicated beyond belief, but does consent have to be in an official contract? Is verbal consent enough? Do you need witnesses to establish it? Can you retract consent? What about consent given in a contract which is later revealed to be under duress - or at least, the contract signatory claims to be?

For every question I ask above, a book has been written on how to exactly define the scope and context of every law in the book. Here is [an entertaining twenty minute video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3kfGIz3u0RA), describing all the laws involved in just the bee example.

And that is not even getting to your system of having the settlement decided by "the populace". The entire country by vote? A jury? Who is eligible? And so on and so forth. You need a book to describe these things adequately.

So what would result from your system? It would cause twenty lawsuits a second, or zero, forever, depending on how the courts interpret your laws. You are essentially handing over the governance to those people, or to the most charismatic lawyers if truly every bit of law interpretation is done by laypeople. Do you even have lawyers?

You're not getting a stable society with a legal system that fits in a tweet. It's not going to happen. For every law you write, try to imagine the most selfish yet charming individual interpreting them to their greatest self-interest. You will soon learn why you need entire books of laws.